# Append a byte array to a string c++ efficiently

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I am processing several chunks of byte arrays (`uint_8`) and append them to a string (`my_string`). For efficiency purposes, I have reserved more than enough bytes for my string by

```
my_string.reserve(more_than_enough_bytes);
```

I am trying to append each chunk as shown in the following function:

```
bool MyClass::AppendToMyString(uint_8* chunk, size_t chunk_num_bytes) {
  memcpy(const_cast<uint_8*>(my_string.data()), chunk, chunk_num_bytes);
  return true;
}
```

But the problem is that `memcpy` does not update `my_string` size. So, next time when this function is called, I do not where the last element was, other than using a separate variable for it. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use the my_string.append method, that's what it is designed for. `my_string.append(chunk, chunk_num_bytes);` You'll probably need a cast from `uint_8*` to `char*`

Comment: I'm surprised `memcpy(my_string, chunk, chunk_num_bytes);` compiles. What type is `my_string`? I've been assuming `std::string` but maybe not.

Comment: Use [`std::string::append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append).  Overload 4 from that page should optimize to a `memcpy` for you.

Comment: `string'`s `size` and `length` methods are guaranteed to be [constant complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time). This means when you call `size`, `string` cannot run off and count the number of characters before the first null. It needs to be able to set the size as the `string` is modified. Since `memcpy` doesn't know it's operation on a `string`, it just sees an address it's supposed to write to, it cannot update the `string`'s size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` has an [`append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) method which will take care of this.  Something along the lines of:

```
void append_chunk (std::string &s, const uint8_t* chunk, size_t chunk_num_bytes)
{
    s.append ((char *) chunk, chunk_num_bytes);
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jYSVk6OfUboA0fJi)